# Upgrading WP to 5.0.1 deletes civicrm uploads folder

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, multisite

When upgrading a WP multisite to 5.0.1, it completely removed contents within the civicrm uploads directory. I then restored the folder from the backup and all worked.

But this is weird, does anyone know why this happens? Has it happened to anyone else? Not feeling secure to upgrade on production yet when I see things like this.

It makes you run a db upgrade for all sites on the network but that shouldn't have anything to do with the uploads folder.

Comment: Did you test local or on your normal host?    WP should not remove any folders and I've not seen that.

Comment: On our normal host. So strange :/

Comment: 5.01 here - not multisite -but no issues @AndyBurns

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing this on my only 5.01 site, which uses the old WP CiviCRM file structure.  That is, the files are in `<webroot>/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm` and not `<webroot>/wp-content/uploads/civicrm`.

Comment: I'm using the new file structure.