# Deleting a site on WP multisite deletes civicrm uploads folder's contents

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Similar to the behavior of this [Upgrading WP to 5.0.1 deletes civicrm uploads folder](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/upgrading-wp-to-5-0-1-deletes-civicrm-uploads-folder), I had deactivated then decided to delete a site on our WP multisite. Once I clicked delete I got a fatal error (sorry I did not copy) that referenced line 916 of civicrm.php file. Deactivating CiviCRM plugin got the multisite backup.

```
require_once 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
      CRM_Core_ClassLoader::singleton()->register();
```

Then I saw that the uploads/civicrm folder was empty. It had the */ext /uploads and /template_c* folder but they were all empty. The rest were gone.

We restored the directory from backup and now it works. Anyways, this is a word of caution.

Question is, why did this happen?

Comment: was the `/uploads/sites/` folder somehow symlinked to `/uploads/civicrm` ?

Comment: Yes,symlinks are still in /uploads/sites/XX. Those symlinks should be removed, right?

Comment: I'd test it first, but Yes, I think the symlinks are the issue.  If WP follows the link when deleting the site it will remove files it should not.    This does bring up a point that we should ensure the documentation is correct on docs.civicrm.org as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a site in WP triggers deleting sites/nn/uploads folder contents. Unfortunately, that site still had a civicrm symlink pointing to /uploads/civicrm which the delete trigger followed and subsequently deleted.

Don't use symlinks. I removed without issue. Instead you can define resource paths in civicrm.settings.php file. Will take a look at updating docs.